# DIfference between 'methodology' and 'method'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I was reading an ELL question, [Is there any good methodology to help remember sound-alike words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2899), and I wondered about the use of 'methodology'. Would someone please affirm or refute it? Would that question have been more accurate if it used the word "method" instead? In other words:

> Is there any good **method** to help remember sound-alike words?

I did some research on this, and found:

- [Method vs. Methodology](http://organizationsandmarkets.com/2007/04/07/method-versus-methodology/)

> Speaking of pet peeves, here’s another of mine: the regular misuse of the word “methodology” in academic papers. Methodology is the study of scientific methods, a branch of epistemology. Econometric techniques, strategies for gathering data, means of testing hypotheses, etc. are methods, not methodologies.

- [Methodology isn't Methods](http://patthomson.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/methodology-isnt-methods-or-what-goes-in-a-methods-chapter/)

> So, after all that, what do I mean by methodology?
>
> Well I understand methodology to be theory; it’s theory about the research methods that will be used. It’s theory which underpins the decisions made about the researcher’s range of choices of – for example – what to study; who to study; where to study; which research tradition to work within; what knowledges to draw on; what to include and exclude, foreground and background and the consequences of this decision; what counts as data and why; relational and ethical concerns; and how to represent the findings/how to write the research.
>
> And I see methods as the ‘tools’ that are used to do the research.

I understand *methodology* to be theory (it’s theory about the research methods that will be used), and I see *methods* as the ‘tools’ that are used to do the research.

Is my understanding accurate? Which would have been the better word to use in the title of the aforementioned question?

Comment: Regardless of how this question gets answered, I think the ELL question you cite should be left as originally written; [here's why](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-should-we-fix-the-problem-of-bad-question-titles-on-ell/381#381).

Answer (score 1):

Methodology and methods may have distinct meanings when discussing research, but for more general conversations, [methodology](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/methodology) can mean a set of procedures.

I think that the question would be better phrased as "Are there any good [**techniques**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/Techniques) to remember sound-alike words?" Methodology connotates a related set of procedures as part of a scientific inquiry, while techniques could be different ways of accomplishing a goal and have the connotation of using specialized knowledge or skill.

For example, "The chef taught me a technique for making perfect soufflés." or "The teacher explained several techniques for remembering homophones."

Comment: alt. "Is there a good method to remember sound-alike words?"

Comment: Method is fine, but it is more of an organized system or plan. "The company developed a new method of packaging rice." Technique or tip is a better choice in my opinion for the intent of the question, because the advice is usually different for different pairs of homophones.